# Is it possible to list all scripts associated with a GDrive File though the Apps Script File Class?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I was wondering if there's a function like file.GetName(), however it would be something like file.GetScripts() to be able to find if a file has container-bound scripts.

see: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getDescription()

Comment: I haven't read all documentation, but maybe in [Importing and Exporting Projects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/import-export), I added a tag to see if anyone there knows this.

Answer (score 1):

I attempted something similar this past summer (summer 2014) and determined it was currently not possible, either via Apps Script nor via the Drive SDK.

In our case we were able to re-structure our project so the scripts we needed to interact with programatically were stand alone files on Drive, which we include in the relevant documents as Libraries.